# Readonly connections with ADO.NET, SQLite and TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sqlite, ado.net, readonly

My code reads via one connection and writes via another. I dont want to accidentally write with the read connection. How can i make the connection readonly? I am using SQLite ATM and will convert sections of code to tsql when the prototype is over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add Read Only=True to the read-only connection.

```
Data Source=filename;Read Only=True;
```