# Programmatically switching database to read-only and write on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, readonly

Can you programmatically switch a database to write access and back to read-only in C#?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004010/readonly-connections-with-ado-net-sqlite-and-tsql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Reference**](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLReadOnly.aspx)

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET READ_ONLY

ALTER DATABASE database-name SET READ_WRITE
```

You can access the stored procedure in c# like below to execute the above lines.

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string expression = "Parameter value";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (dr.Read()) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Does this require some kind of admin access also?

Comment: Yes. sys admin can play with these games.