# ALTER DATABASE query for Access not working

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have a C# application which has Access as its back end database.  The database is password protected and becomes read-only automatically. I need to programmatically make it read-write. For this I wrote the following code:

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Windows\Database5.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=<redacted>;");
 con.Open();
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("ALTER DATABASE Database5.accdb SET READ_WRITE", con);
 OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (dr.Read() == true)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("database altered");
 }
 else
 {
    MessageBox.Show("not altered");
 }
```

The error I am getting is: `invalid SQL syntax. Expected token: password`

Comment: As far as I know there is no ALTER DATABASE ..... SET READ_WRITE for an MS Access database

Comment: You really shouldn't post your password.

Comment: @tnw: can u please tell me how can i complete my requirement

Comment: @abhishekkulkarni I'm not familiar enough with SQL to help... just letting you know it's incredibly stupid to publicly post your password. You should be more careful in the future.

Comment: @Steve: i actually checked this link on stack over flow. followed it to code my program but it is not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026456/programmatically-switching-database-to-read-only-and-write-on-sql-server

Comment: That link tells you how to change a SQL database.  You are using Access.  Apples to oranges...

Comment: That question is about Sql Server not Ms-Access @Brian that's the point

Comment: i agree but then how can i work with the query. it is requesting a password as token. i think even sql database alter query has a password token...is that so ?

Answer (score 2):

As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177884%28v=office.12%29.aspx), `ALTER DATABASE` in Access SQL can only be used to change the database password. Unlike in T-SQL (SQL Server) here is no `ALTER DATABASE` query in Access to change the read/write status of a database.